# Interpret $\int_0^1 \sqrt{4 - x^2}\,dx$ geometrically and find the area

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Sadly I'm stuck on this one. Now I now I could resort to finding the antiderivative  $F$ and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus (i.e. $F(b) - F(a)$), but that isn't asked (or introduced by the book) at this point.

So, we're dealing with a circle with $r = 2$ here. The entire quadrant would have area $\pi$, following from $A = \pi r^2$, but we're only interested in the area between $0$ and $1$.

First I drew a quarter circle and observed that I certainly have a 1 unit squared area where $x$ and $y$ are between $0$ and $1$, then I refined this a bit using the fact that when $x = 1$, $y = \sqrt 3$. So now I'm stuck with an area of $\sqrt 3$, but there's a bit of circle left.

So I start toying around a bit, with say $x = 0.5$ and find $\sqrt{ 3.75}$, basically go brute force on it and come to some approximation, but that doesn't really contribute to a deeper understanding of the subject.

How do I approach and solve this more analytically (take in to consideration that this is the first batch of integrals I'm trying to solve, so not too advanced please ;))?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Instead of thinking of a rectangle and a bit of circle, think triangle (half of that rectangle) and a sector.

Comment: Thanks, had to look in to circle sectors, my geometry was lacking for this exercise.

Answer (score 2):

It is the area of the semi-circle $x^2+y^2 = 4, y \ge 0$ bounded by $y$-axis and the line $x=1.$

Comment: Surely we only want a quarter-circle.

Comment: @J.G. not the full quarter though!

Comment: The answer as suggested by Arthur is going to be $\frac {2 \pi} {3} + \frac {\sqrt 3} {2} = 2.96\ (\text {approx}.) < \pi.$

Comment: Yeah, the answer is in the back of the book. I only wanted a hint on the approach :)

Answer (score 1):

Doing a sketch for the function that you're integrating is always a good idea. If you already know how to do sketches, check Desmos.com, a great tool to visualize your functions.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aeyqiwtnhq